# I have 64 bit Java, but no jdk folder in my Program Files\Java folder?

Tags: java, path-variables

I'm trying to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable - I need to set it to the 64 bit version.

To make sure I have the 64 bit version, I checked `java -version` by the cmd prompt, and got the output:

```
Java version "1.7.0_25" 
Java<TM> SE Runtime Environment <build 1.7.0_25-b17>
Java Hotspot<TM> 64-bit Server VM <build 23.25-b01, mixed mode>
```

I'm assuming the last line verifies I have 64-bit... so I went to check the exact path to type into the environment variable, and found that `Program Files\Java\` does not contain a `jdk` folder. However, `Program Files (x86)\Java\` does. Instead, the former only has a `jre7` folder.

I can't direct my environment variable to the 32-bit folder because `Android Studio` keeps telling me that I need 64-bit java. What am I missing?

(If this belongs on SuperUser and not here, just comment below and i'll delete the question here)

Comment: sounds like you don't have the jdk at all.  You wouldn't, unless you downloaded it on purpose.

Comment: I have a `jdk1.7.0_03` folder in `Program Files (x86)\Java` , and Eclipse seems to work fine.

Comment: On second read, my previous comment was too opaque.  The JRE and JDK are two different things.  Unless you specifically chose to download the JDK (which does come with a matching JRE) you got the JRE, which will run java apps just fine (including eclipse), but won't let you compile anything

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. What confuses me is that there is a `jdk` folder though. Does this still not mean that I have JDK? And if it doesn't, is it okay to install JDK without uninstalling JRE?

Comment: Does it have a  javac.exe in the bin directory?  If so, It's probably a JDK.

Comment: looking at your comments to the other answers, lets assume you don't have a JDK, or the JDK you have isn't valid.  Best bet is to download a fresh copy

Comment: Yes, there is a `javac` executable in `Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`.

Comment: Try setting your JAVA_HOME to that directory, minus the `bin`.

Comment: I have; however, `Android Studio` tells me that I need to direct it to 64-bit JDK. Is it possible that my version is only 32 bit?

Comment: yes, that's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it by simply installing 64-bit JDK.

Comment: FYI, a JRE (R = Runtime) is a subset of a JDK (D = Development), able to run Java apps but not compile and build apps. A JRE has the `java` program but no `javac` program, where a JDK has both.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking at JRE

type

```
javac -version
```

in your command line

Comment: For some reason, I get the error that `javac` isn't a command. Does this mean I do not have JDK?

Comment: I think you installed JRE instead of JDK. Install it properly and add path in environment variables.

Comment: Okay, the command wasn't working earlier, but I edited the path and put in the `bin` folder, so now when I call `javac -version` I get the output `javac 1.7.0_03`

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple Javas installed.  Sounds like you have a 32 bit JDK and a 64 bit JRE.  64 bit software is installed in the "program files" folder, and 32 bit software is installed in the "program files (x86)" folder.

a 64 bit JDK will live in /program files/java/jdkxxx

Download the 64 bit JDK installer and install it, and then point your JAVA_HOME to it.

The installer takes care of this so far as I remember, but you will want to modify your PATH variable as well to point to %JAVA_HOME%/bin; ... add that to the front of the path so that typing Java will find your JDK first.

Answer (score 0):

your JDK will have a jre folder...set your JAVA_HOME pointing to that as that is what android studio will expect as the JAVA_HOME env

Comment: If I point it to `Program Files\Java\jre7`, Android Studio gives me an error stating `'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during the installation (JDK download)) you probably chose like me the "x64 installer" instead of the "x64 MSI Installer" which was right under it, and it probably didnt create the required "JDK" folder so you can set the "JAVA_HOME" path correctly. In order to rectify this. go and download it and then change the environment variables for the "JAVA_HOME" to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin" or whatever version you are currently using and it should probably work after a restart. I hope this helped someone in 2024 because i spent a lot of time trying to figure it out myself.